# Date input validation using ng-change, AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-change

I's using AngularJS and [AngularJS bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) in my page. I have a date picker directive that looks like this:

```
    <div class="form-group {{dateStatus.class}}">
        <p class="input-group">
            <input type="text" id="inpDate" class="form-control" 
                   datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy" ng-model="task.date" 
                   is-open="datePickerStatus.isOpen" min-date="minDate" 
                   datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" 
                   close-text="Close" placeholder="Due date" 
                   ng-change="checkDateValidity()"
            />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
                        ng-click="openDatePicker($event)"
                >
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                </button>
            </span>
        </p>
    </div>
```

To validate the date input, in my controller I have the following function:

```
        $scope.checkDateValidity = function(){
        var date,
            isValid,
            taskDate;
        taskDate = $scope.task.date;
        date = new Date(taskDate);
        isValid = !isNaN(date);
        if(isValid) {
            $scope.addButtonState.isOk = true;
            $scope.dateStatus.class = '';
        }
        else{
            $scope.addButtonState.isOk = false;
            $scope.dateStatus.class = 'has-error';
        }
    }
```

everything works fine for checking if the date inserted is valid, but the problem is that when the date input is left blank(or changed from a valid state to blank)
 I want it to be acceptable too, but since both empty input and invalid date are `undefined`I don't know how to declare between the cases.

I also thought of reading the input text directly like this:

```
document.getElementById('inpDate').value
```

but the ng-change is fired when the value is changed and I'm left with the previous value which is useless now...

thanks for your time and response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily validate `#inpDate` value by binding validator callback to both `change` and `keyup` events, then when your callback triggered you can check the validity of your input.

```
$timeout(function(){        
    angular
        .element(document.getElementById('inpDate'))
        .bind('keyup change', function(){
            var inputValue,
                customDate,
                isValid;

            inputValue = this.value;
            if(inputValue != ''){
                customDate = new Date(inputValue);
                isValid = !isNaN(customDate);

                if(isValid){
                    console.log('Valid');
                    // do something
                }
                else{
                    console.log('Invalid');
                    // do something else
                }
            }
            else{
                console.log('Empty');
                // do something else
            }
        });
}, 400);
```

Please make sure that your have injected `$timeout` in your controller.

Comment: it is not recommended to access form elements directly from the controller

Comment: @Kunal Yes, But I have just fixed a specific problem. The question's author can build a directive and use this method in that.

Answer (score 7):

A much better way of validating is using a directive to add a Validation Rule.

```
.directive("validateDate", function() {
     return {
         require: 'ngModel',
         link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
             ctrl.$validators.validateDate = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
                 if(!isNaN(modelValue) || ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)){
                     return true;
                 }
                 return false;
             };
         }
     };
 })
```

then you just need to add `validate-date` to the input tag and the validation will mark the input as valid if it is !isNaN (when the date is a number OR is empty)

Comment: But the `ng-change` still triggered regardless of the result. Should we move all the change event logic to the validation directive instead?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to validate like that, then you can use

```
if(document.getElementById('inpDate').value === "" ){
            $scope.addButtonState.isOk = true;
            $scope.dateStatus.class = '';
}
```

this at the beginning of the `$scope.checkDateValidity` function

Comment: The OP has already mentioned that, he has tried this method and it's not working.

Comment: Else validate `$scope.task.date` like that, I don't understand what is not working here