# JavaScript regex for username validation

Tags: javascript, regex, angular5

I tried with many patters for username in my Angular5 application. But didn't get a suitable solution for my requirement.

### The Rules are

Minimum 6 characters 
Only numbers are not allowed at least one character should be there 
No special characters allowed except _ 
No space allowed 
Character only is allowed

I tried with `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([_]?[a-zA-Z0-9])*$/`

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]*[a-zA-Z0-9](?<![_\s\-]{6,}.*)$/
```

Comment: What did you try? where is your code/efforts?

Comment: Could you add your code?

Comment: I have handled minimum number separately because I want to display a message for that case. My issue is only number case is not able to validate. @VicJordan Allan

Comment: Is this fine? "/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]*[a-zA-Z0-9](?<![-?\d+\.?\d*$]{6,}.*)$/"

Comment: Vimal, did my regex solved your issue?

Comment: Yes @Allan. Thank you.. :)

Comment: I don't think it can be solved by regex only, or it will be a bit too complex / hard to maintain. Perhaps check algorithmically on `ngChange` instead. Or with `$validators` if it is still usable in Angular: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23595975/date-input-validation-using-ng-change-angularjs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{5,}[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*$
```

- [a-zA-Z0-9_]{5,} to match at least five alphanumerics and the underscore
- [a-zA-Z]+ to have at least one letter
- [0-9]* to match zero to any occurrence of the given numbers range

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regex:

```
^(?=[a-z_\d]*[a-z])[a-z_\d]{6,}$
```

in case insensitive mode as tested on regex101: [**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/JcgFjQ/3)

Explanations:

- `^` anchor for the beginning of the string
- `$` anchor for the end of the string
- `(?=[a-z_\d]*[a-z])` to force the presence of at least one letter
- `[a-z_\d]{6,}` implement the at least 6 char constraint

Answer (score -1):

Yes this is fine for me. Thanks.`/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]*[a-zA-Z0-9](?<![-?\d+\.?\d*$]{6,}.*)$/`

Comment: No fail for this. "5mm656565v5". :(